# Sympy Dummy symbol in the derivative could not be replaced

Tags: python, sympy

I have a very long expression where, after the derivative, the term with the dummy variable `_xi_1` appeared,

```
Subs(Derivative(eta(_xi_1), _xi_1), _xi_1, 0)

type(exp_list[0].args[2].args[2].args[1][0])
sympy.core.symbol.Dummy
```

I tried to replace the dummy variable with the new symbol `s`

```
[e_xi_1 ] = exp_list[0].args[2].args[2].args[1][0].free_symbols
```

it did not work,

```
for ix in exp_list:
    print(  ix.subs(_xi_1 ,s) )
```

still print out the derivative with respect to `_xi_1`.

This is important because though

```
Subs(Derivative(eta(_xi_1), _xi_1), _xi_1, 0)  == Subs(Derivative(eta(s), s), s, 0)
True
```

when I tried to substitute the expressions such as `Subs(Derivative(eta(s), s), s, 0)` from a list, it would not replace `Subs(Derivative(eta(_xi_1), _xi_1), _xi_1, 0)`.

How to replace the dummy variable so that the `Subs(Derivative(eta(_xi_1), _xi_1), _xi_1, 0)` could be replaced to `Subs(Derivative(eta(s), s), s, 0)` so that it could be replaced to the numerical values?

---

A reproducible example

```
from sympy import Function
eta = Function('eta')
from sympy import *

eta = Function('eta')
s, x=symbols('s x',real =True)

exp_01=1/eta(s+x)* exp(-2*pi*exp(exp(s) +x))*(1- exp(-2*pi*exp(exp(s) +x)) )
exp_02 = exp_01.diff(s,5).subs(s,0).subs(x,0).expand()

dummy_symbol = exp_02.args[9].args[1].args[0].args[1][0]
```

if you compare the expressions in

```
exp_02
```

and

```
exp_02.subs(dummy_symbol, s) # the dummy symbol won't be replaced

exp_02.subs(Subs(Derivative(eta(dummy_symbol), dummy_symbol), dummy_symbol, 0),2)
exp_02.subs(Subs(Derivative(eta(s), s), s, 0),2)
exp_02.subs(Subs(Derivative(eta(s), (s, 0)), s, 0),2)
```

some derivatives might be substituted, but lots of the expressions that ought to be substituted remained.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show enough code to know why the subs is failing because (tested locally) it should not fail if you have the right symbol:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, y
f = Function('f')
>>> a=f(x).diff(x).subs(x,0).subs(x,y); a
Subs(Derivative(f(y), y), y, 0)
>>> b = _
>>> a==b
True
>>> a.subs(b,0) == 0
False
>>> a.replace(lambda x:x==b,lambda x:0) == 0
True
```

In a more complicated expression, the replacement appears to fail. For purposes of unifying the instances so you can replace them with values you can try the following workaround:

```
>>> eq = exp_02; x = dummy_symbol; z=Dummy('0')
>>> temp = eq.xreplace(dict([(i,z+i.subs(x,s)) for i in eq.atoms(Subs)]))
>>> temp.subs(...your desired values for Subs instances...).subs(z,0)
```

Comment: See the example in the post, this example is very reproducible. I think it's been there for a while but this case it's very hard to get ride of.

Comment: workaround suggestion given

Comment: I have tried various `.subs()` and didn't work(dummy variable no replacement). I also tried to convert it to `str()`, `simplify()`, it also automatically converted back to the dummy variables again. There's definitely something wrong with the dummy variables usage somewhere. I also tried a slight alternations of the solution you provided, it didn't work. Once the `dummy_symbol` appeared, it seemed to automatically partially overwrite all the other expressions. I'm trying the `.replace()` method to evaluate the expression directly, but encountered some challenges.

Comment: Try to duplicate what I have done. You should be able to confirm that `temp.has(x) is False`. Furthermore, if I do `temp.xreplace(dict(zip(temp.atoms(Subs), range(5)))).has(Subs)`, that, too, is False because they were all replaced with integer values.